# Shopify ApplicationCharge delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

With an applicationcharge and testing them, is their a way to delete unneeded ones later? I can't see a delete example on this api page: http://api.shopify.com/applicationcharge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete an ApplicationCharge. An ApplicationCharge is a one-time, immediate charge (once activated).